# backup inode table on ext2/3/4

Tags: filesystems, backup, data-recovery

is it possible, to backup on regular basis inode table (including all inode information) on ext2/3/4? If yes, how to do it, or which program to use?

Comment: I guess you can use dd to do so, requires a bit of knowledge about the file system. I don't know how exactly though, so I am not posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
e2image - Save critical ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem metadata to a file
```

Comment: Can you please explain this command?

Comment: @AyushGoyal `man e2image`